# The increase does not display the result

Tags: javascript

I'am a debutant. I try to show the result. I would like to know what is the problem and To have a solution. Please help me.

Html

```
 <form name="facturation" id="facturation">
            Prix unitaire <input type="text" name="prixunitaire" id="prixunitaire"/> €
            </br>
            Quantité <input type="text" name="quantite" value="1" id="quantite"/>
            </br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="valider" id="myBtn">Valider</button>
            </br>
            <p id="demo"></p>

        </form>
```

Javascript

Event Click

```
var x = document.getElementById("myBtn");
if (x.addEventListener) {
x.addEventListener("click", eventClick);
} else if (x.attachEvent) {
x.attachEvent("onclick", eventClick);
}
```

Multiplication

```
function eventClick(){
var field1, field2, resultat, txt = '';
field1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("prixUnitaireValue")).value;
field2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantiteValue")).value;
resultat = (field1 * field2);
```

Text

```
if (resultat.textContent) {
    txt = resultat.textContent;
} else if(resultat.innerText) {
    txt = resultat.innerText
} else {
    txt = '';
}
```

Resultat

```
document.getElementById("demo") = txt;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the solution is like this... you have to prevent the form from submitting if you want to render the result into the html element.

- remove the type="submit" from the button
- add evt.preventDefault() in the click handler
- the lines with parseInt were incorectly bracketed
- simplified the resultat handling... no hassle with the text content

HTML:

```
    <form name="facturation" id="facturation">
        Prix unitaire <input type="text" name="prixunitaire" id="prixunitaire"/> €
        </br>
        Quantité <input type="text" name="quantite" value="1" id="quantite"/>
        </br>
        <button value="valider" id="myBtn">Valider</button>
        </br>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
    function eventClick(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var field1, field2, resultat, txt = '';
        field1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("prixunitaire").value);
        field2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantite").value);
        resultat = (field1 * field2);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resultat;
        return false;
    };

    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    if (x.addEventListener) {
    x.addEventListener("click", eventClick);
    } else if (x.attachEvent) {
    x.attachEvent("onclick", eventClick);
    }
```

JS Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/z0q7mjvL/14/